# Blazor Server App call SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

I have a new Blazor Server App, basic counter app.  Running on my localhost.  I would like to create a .razor page that pulls data from a SharePoint list.  What is the best way to do this.  I briefly tried to use PnP.Core but hit permission issues, as I think the app is running locally.  I tried Graph but was a bit unsure.  I have a SP Client ID and Secret.

Any idea what the easyiest way to do this is.

TIA

Comment: you have to solve the permission issues either way. you have two options: you can use an app identity, or you can use the identity of the logged in user. PnP.Core is fine, raw REST API is fine, Graph is fine if you're using a logged in user. But you have to authenticate either way.

Comment: if you're looking for "easy" an app identity or service account is the way to go.